# Oracle - privileges to get metadata from server

Tags: sql, oracle, metadata, privileges

What minimum privileges my user needs to get metadata (name of tables, columns, functions, etc.) from oracle server?

I need to select from:

```
dba_segments
dba_users
all_tables
all_tab_comments
all_views
all_procedures
all_source
all_tab_columns
all_col_comments
all_indexes
all_ind_columns
all_constraints
all_dependencies
all_cons_columns
```

Edit:

I changed conception. Now I need select from table with prefix **dba**% (for example dba_tables, dba_views, etc.).

What minimum privileges I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GRANT SELECT ON sys.dba_segments TO user1;
GRANT SELECT ON sys.dba_users TO user1;
```

Querying ALL_* views require no additional privilege.

Comment: Thanks. Create session grant is also required.